# Ratchet socket from Android and IOS clients

Tags: javascript, android, ios, sockets, ratchet

I've written socket PHP code using [Ratchet](http://socketo.me)  . Here is simple code, that works when I send and get messages from web - javascript:

```
    use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;

    class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface{
        protected $clients;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->clients = new SplObjectStorage();
        }

        function onOpen(\Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn)
        {
            echo "Did Open\n";
            $this->clients->attach($conn);
        }


        function onClose(\Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn)
        {
            echo "Did Close\n";
            $this->clients->detach($conn);
        }


        function onError(\Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
        {
            echo "The following error occured: ". $e->getMessage();
        }


        function onMessage(\Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
        {
            $msgObj = json_decode($msg);
            echo $msgObj->msg;
            foreach($this->clients as $client){
                if($client !== $from){
                    $client->send($msg);
                }
            }
        } 
}
```

The problem is when I use java client - from Android App. I use thread from Activity. It has no exceptions, no errors. client.isConnected()  is true. But no server code is not called - onOpen method, onMessage and others. How Can I fix this. Almost the same situation is with IOS. Client Connects to server but nither of those Ratchet methods are called. They are called only from javascript. Java code :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    client = new Socket("XX.XX.XX.XX", 2000);

                    printWriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
                    printWriter.write("Android Message");
                    printWriter.flush();
                    printWriter.close();
                    client.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use for 
 
Android: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket 
iOS: https://github.com/square/SocketRocket 
Because Ratchet is WebSocket. And your host name should starts from ws://

Comment: Thanks man, java lib helped. I wonder, what is the problem with native java Socket class. Why should I use third party libraries from github with basic socketing ? Maybe this library (provided by you, Java) uses some protocols that are needed for this, don't know. I will give the solution to my squirrel iOS developer and give feedback today if iOS Rocket Socket library works either. Thank you mister anyway !

Comment: From memory the built in Java Socket class is not designed for websockets rather direct binary connections to a server port.  Therefore it doesn't conform to the WebSocket handshake specs so onopen and such aren't fired.

Comment: @MarshallOfSound now I see the problem, took me a day using Java Sokets. Now it works with Web Socket library. thanks

Comment: @MishaAkopov, could you let me know, what is the web socket library did you use for this?

Comment: And for client @MishaAkopov?